# Remove all commas in <title> tags

Tags: html, regex, replace, find, dreamweaver

The last person in my position was comma happy in the title tags. I need to remove all commas in the title tags of 40,000 html product pages. Is there a regex expression to find all commas in a title tag? I am hoping I can find the all the commas with a regex expression and replace them in dreamweaver. Is this possible?

The format usually follows

(opening title tag)Product, Product, 81120,
(opening title tag)Product Product, Product, 98564,
(opening title tag)Product Product, Product Product, 98564,
(opening title tag)Product, Product Product, 98564,

the number at the end is a 5 digit product #

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please give us the exact format, is it all between <title></title>? You're going to have to be a bit more specific

Comment: Is there really no closing title tag?

Comment: <title>Word, Word, 81120, Word Word Word Word</title>

Comment: It is all between  the <title></title> tags

Comment: sorry I wasnt more specific

Answer (score 2):

You can look for a comma after which `</title>` is what follows after the first `<` after the comma and replace them with an empty string:

```
,(?=[^<]*</title>)
```

Note that this assumes you will be doing this in an editor. Never trust regexes when it comes to unknown HTML. If you'll be using this in code, it's better to use a DOM parser to scope your replace correctly. It also assumes that either the string `</title>` will not appear out of context (such as in javascript code) or you can review the replacement process manually wherever this regex might get confused. (whose idea was to have 40k HTML files, again? Hopefully they don't create new title tags!).

Answer (score 1):

Good blog describing how to do it in PHP: http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/how-to-match-and-replace-content-between-two-html-tags-using-regular-expressions

I would think to do this in dreamweaver you would want something using a back reference like:

`(<Title>\S\s),+(\S\s<\/Title>)`

With this in the Replace:
$1 $2

**As pointed out** - would need to loop this to success - was thinking this was something the IDE would support, but that is probably not the case.

Good post here: http://somerandomdude.com/2006/05/25/dreamweaver-regular-expressions/

Comment: You would need to run this regex several times to get rid of all commas.

Comment: Caveat: unfamiliar with dreamweaver and adapted .

Comment: Why put \ before , in []? Only groups (\s for spaces, \S for non-spaces) require escaping.

Comment: @Destrictor closing braces and backslashes need escaping too, even in character classes

Comment: @Destrictor was modifying earlier answer without adding thought.

Comment: @JanDvorak So - will putting a regex into dreamweaver and hitting 'Replace All' (if this is an option) not run the regex until it fails?

Comment: @Matthew I would guess it does not replace overlapping matches or recursively. Otherwise, it could run into infinite loops.

Comment: Two more upgrades: why is the comma wrapped in a character class, and why is it wrapped in a capturing group?

Comment: @JanDvorak Both improved - and upvoted yours as better answer :)

Answer (score -3):

You can use this
regexp: `([\,]+)`

Comment: This will remove all commas, not just in the title.

Comment: I am interested in the regexp. Are you still updating it?